# How to select the first row which has the max value in each group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to select the max value of each group. But when there are multiple rows with the same value, I only want to select the first one, how can I do that?

For example, the table is something like:

```
Group  Name  Value
A A1 20
A A2 20
A A3 10
B B1 20
B B2 30
B B3 30
B B4 10
```

The result I want is

```
A A1 20
B B2 30
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25

Comment: Then the row_number approach given will work

Comment: @Error_2646 that approach work for version 8, not for 5.7

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Doh, yeah. I just saw the 14's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "the first row", because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, you need a column to specify what "first" is.

You can easily get *one* row.  One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where (name, value) = (select name, value
                       from t t2
                       where t2.group = t.group
                       order by t2.value desc
                       limit 1
                      );
```

In MySQL 8+, the canonical way would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by group order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The first one does work for me.But I am not quite understand the algorithm. The query in the parentheses seems can not work by itself because t is not defined there. Then how can it works while using combined together? Could you please explain this for me? Thank you.

Comment: @yixizhou . . . This is called a *correlated subquery*.  You can find more information in the MySQL documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html.

Comment: That really helps. Thank you so much.